# is there combination char which is of Bar , line in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, charts

I need to implement combination chart .
[image]

As the reference image , is it possible to achieve it in React JS ?
could anyone help me with reference link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the React porting of chart.js and read this documentation:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html?h=mixed

The chart.js react package you can use is this:

https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2

Answer (score 0):

Referencing my previous answer: [Create the Mixed Chart in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155194/create-the-mixed-chart-in-react/75293453#75293453)

USE APEXCHARTS. I tried literally everything and apexcharts was the easiest of all the charts for reactjs. LMK if you have anymore questions!

https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/mixed-charts/line-column/#

NOTE: the doc doesn't mention it but you want to import ReactApexCharts from the library like below.

you're gonna need to convert the class states into functional component states in react which shouldn't be too hard if you know basic React. Here's what your inside code should similarly look like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts";

export default function Graph(props) {

  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: "line",
    },
    stroke: {
      width: [0, 4],
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      enabledOnSeries: [1],
    },
    labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5'],
    // xaxis: { DONT NEED THIS, but if you check out the docs they have some useful stuff.
    //   type: 'datetime'
    // },
    yaxis: [
      {
        title: {
          text: "Total Number of Sessions",
        },
      },
      {
        opposite: true,
        title: {
          text: "Total Traffic (Gbps)",
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  const [series, setSeries] = useState([
    {
      name: "Total Number of Sessions",
      type: "column",
      data: [440, 505, 414, 671, 227]//your data goes here
    },
    {
      name: "Total Traffic (Gbps)",
      type: "line",
      data: [40, 50, 41, 67, 22]//your data goes here
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <ReactApexChart
        options={options}
        series={series}
        type='line'
        height={350}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```